# Unable to set transparency in custom cell created programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with custom cells, based in Tweetie's [Fast scrolling example](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/) and i need transparency.

Until now, i loaded my cells from a nib and all i needed was to set some table's properties to

```
table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
table.opaque = NO;
table.rowHeight = 130.0f;
table.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

in order to make the table transparent. As for the cell, i did:

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbackground.png"]];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbackground.png"]];
```

And so i had every cell with a background image but with the rest completely transparent (half of the image is completely transparent). Now, creating the cell programmatically and drawing everything myself, i just can't get to make the cell transparent. The image part looks fine, but everything else is black, not opaque

Comment: Did you set the backgroundColor of the cell to a clearColor? *cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

The issue was that it wasn't paying attention to my

```
self.opaque = NO;
```

because my cell's super class was doing exactly the opposite, setting opaque = YES;. So i changed that and it is working great now.

PS: Thanks for answering and making me pay extra attention to opaque property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
```

You may also need this:

```
cell.opaque = NO;
```

Comment: I've done it, with no result. I think the problem is that Twitter app draws everything by hand, so my cell's superview does: - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)r { [(ABTableViewCell *)[self superview] drawContentView:r]; } and in that call, -i think, it disables everything i might set. Drawing everything by hand is what makes it fast and the reason i want to use this code, but i can't put this two things together.